# Kendo Template check box not firing click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview

I have used Kendo Template as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Module/Analysis/CreateMaintainAnalysis.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="Modeltemplate">
        <div class="section group fr">
            <div class="col span_2_of_12">
                #if(ACTIVE_MODELS_COUNT > 0){# <input class="ModelCheckBox"  type="checkbox"  checked/>#} else {# <input class="ModelCheckBox" type="checkbox" unchecked/>  #}#
            </div>
            <div class="col span_4_of_12"><label>#:MODEL#</label></div>
        </div>
      </script>
```

and I want to write click event on CheckBox Click as follows:

```
$("#ModelListView").kendoListView({
    template: kendo.template($("#Modeltemplate").html())
});

     $(".ModelCheckBox").click(function () {
        if (this.checked) { alert("Checked"); }
         });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, the click handler is attached too early, before the ListView is data bound, so there are still no checkboxes rendered. You have two options -

1. Execute the code below in the `dataBound` event of the ListView.

   http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listview#events-dataBound

   ```
   $(".ModelCheckBox").click(function () {
      if (this.checked) { alert("Checked"); }
   });
   ```
2. Use a delegate that is attached to the ListView `<div>`

   ```
   $("#ModelListView").on("click", ".ModelCheckBox", function () {
      if (this.checked) { alert("Checked"); }
   });
   ```