# Checkbox inside Kendo template does not get disabled

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-template

Hi I am using Kendo template as follows:

```
 <div id="ModelListView"></div>

    <div class="section group fr">
             #if(MODEL != null){#
                #if(ACTIVE_MODELS_COUNT  > 0 && ACTIVE_MODELS_COUNT != 'null'){#
                    <input class="ModelCheckBox" type="checkbox"  checked/>
                #}
                else {#
                    <input class="ModelCheckBox" type="checkbox" unchecked />    
                #}#
                    <label>#:MODEL#</label>
                    <label class="Model_ID" style="visibility:hidden;">#:MODEL_ID#</label>
                    @*<input class="Model_ID" type="hidden" value= #:MODEL_ID #/>*@
                #}#
        </div>
 $("#ModelListView").kendoListView({
      template: kendo.template($("#Modeltemplate").html())
 });
```

I want to disable the checkbox based on some condition but not able to do it.

```
 $(".ModelCheckBox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: you want disabled or unchecked?

Comment: Diasabled..I dont want it to be checked...

Comment: can you create a DOJO/Codepen that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Sure I will do that

Comment: Basically this kendo template is inside the DIV..pls refer the Question again i have updated it...

Comment: Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/JKqRQr  you can click the enable and disable buttons and it seems to work fine... Can you edit the codepen to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the recommended usage of `prop()` instead of `attr()`, demonstrated by **ezanker**, make sure that you disable the checkboxes after they are actually rendered, i.e. do that in the ListView's `dataBound` event [(similar to another question of yours)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38724584/3086237). Alternatively, include your disable logic in the template markup.